# Noun Denoting Exponential Growth in a Small Time Frame?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

I’m currently working on a history assignment that involves describing the expansion of the west, after the American Civil War. I *could*, in theory, grit my teeth and simply get over my reluctance to use more words than I really have to—but . . . Well, I, uh . . . /cough//cough/ . . . /awkwardly laughs/

Anyway! I was going to include the impact that the construction of railroads had on the economy; basically, it minimized the effort people had to exert in order to travel around. It was easier to get to other cities, towns, and (maybe) even states—more people settled in the western areas, which had been previously been next to impossible to traverse, courtesy of the Appalachian Mountains. Due to this, the economy was thriving.

What I would like to find out is whether a noun exists that denotes “an [extreme] growth in a very short period of time”. The reason I’m requesting a noun is for this reason:

> Transcontinental railroads conjoined the Atlantic coast with that of the Pacific, which directly resulted in (extreme economic growth in a short period of time).

Any and all suggestions are appreciated, and thanks for your time!

Comment: Your question's title says *growth* and not **economic growth**, which you're asking in your detailed question. What is this about ? Which one do ya need?

Comment: .....Explosion.

Answer (score 4):

**boom**

a rapid increase in price, development, numbers, etc.:
*a boom in housing construction.*

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/boom?s=t

Answer (score 1):

I would say

> Transcontinental railroads joined the Atlantic and Pacific coasts, which prompted an (economic boom)/(explosion of economic growth).

(Sorry to edit the first half of your sentence as well, but I found it a bit wordy.)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid be pedantic, you could just say

> ...which directly resulted in unprecedented national economic expansion